# Preventing multiple executions of observer

Tags: angular, rxjs, observable

I have the following code that performs an HTTP call, gets the response, and analyzes it. in case it contains an applicative error, I want to fire the observer.error, also I want to forward the original error received from the httpClient observer.
I created my own observable and wrapped the HTTP call.
It's working, however, in the case of many subscribers, the HTTP call will perform many times. and if no subscribers, the call will not be executed.
Before the wrapping, by using the httpClient observer, it worked fine (event with many subscribers)

How to improve the following code to prevent multiple execute despite multiple subscribers?

```
public oldApiCall<T>(url: string, httpParams: string): Observable<T> {
      let myobs: Observable<T> = new Observable((observer: Observer<T>) => {
      let obs: Observable<any>;
      //console.log("calling "+url + httpParams);
      obs = this.httpClient.get<T>(url + httpParams).pipe(share());
      obs.subscribe((data) => {
        try
        {
          //console.log("call of "+url + httpParams+" returned \n"+JSON.stringify(data));
          let err : ResponseError = data;
          //alert('err '+err.error.data)
          err.error.message = err.error.data;          
          console.error("error occured when calling "+url+httpParams+"\n"+JSON.stringify(err));
          observer.error(err.error);
          
        }
        catch(e)
        {
          observer.next(data);
          observer.complete();
        }
        
      },(err)=>
      {
        observer.error(err);
        console.error("http call error "+err+" when calling "+url+httpParams);
      })
    })  
    myobs.subscribe() //To ensure the call is executed event if there are no subscribers
    return myobs;
```

Comment: Can you try `return myobs.pipe(share());`? Is that possible? But I think you need that `share()` or `shareReplay(1)` on it as well.

Comment: Unfortunately, I tested that before and it's not helping

Comment: Actually, This helped with one more addition, moving the myobs.subscribe() to the calling function.